# Como habilito una columna para insertar registros y guardarlo c# gridcontrol devexprees

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridview

El que tengo lo hice agregando una columna y habilitando el allow edit del gridview, pero al momento de saltar a la siguiente celda se borra lo que escribi[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

si doy enter o solo cambio de celda igual se borra, si es una tabla normal de sql, ese campo lo voy a guardar, pero primero quiero que quede en la tabla para capturarlo

Comment: le das con enter o te mueves con la flecha ¿? es una simple tabla con base de datos¿? el campo se te guarda solamente en tu base de datos y desaparece del campo o no aparece en ambos?

Comment: Agregaste la condicion de update e insert para la tabla?? o solo la edicion?

Comment: Estas usando XpCollections o XpDataView?

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que tu columna "Verificar" tenga vacía la propiedad "FieldName".

Debes enlazar la columna del grid a un campo de tu base de datos, mediante el FieldName.